# Erro ao criar link dinamicamente

Tags: php, bbcode

Consegui o seguinte código BBCode que atende perfeitamente a lógica do que estou precisando para criar link. Só que o mesmo apresenta os seguintes erros:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   /home/p3h8com/public_html/teste.php on line 3
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in
>   /home/p3h8com/public_html/teste.php on line 3

```
$str = '[url=http://www.abc.com.br]Blog do Beraldo[/url]';
$str = preg_replace( "/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i", "<a href="\&quot;$1\&quot;" target="\&quot;blank\&quot;">$2</a>", $str );
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Está dando quebra de string. Você está delimitando os atributos do HTML com aspas duplas e ao mesmo tempo a string do PHP.

```
"<a href="\&quot;$1\&quot;" target="\&quot;blank\&quot;">$2</a>"
         ↑                ↑        ↑                   ↑
```

Altere as aspas dos atributos com aspas simples que resolve, e não precisa dos códigos `\&quot;`, porque irá gerar aspas desnecessárias invalidando o link:

```
$str = '[url=http://www.abc.com.br]Blog do Beraldo[/url]';
$str = preg_replace( "/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i", "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$2</a>", $str );
echo $str;
```